# Javascript / ES7: do I need to bind 'this' in my particular Web Component class constructor?

Tags: javascript, web-component, ecmascript-2016

My code works, but I was taught to bind 'this' to the event listener function. In my web component class constructor, I have a button in the shadow root. In the constructor I also added the click event listener on the button and went ahead and defined the on click function as an arrow function, ie `this.clickHandler = (e) => {...}`. However, I did not bind 'this' to the event listener function, I just used `this.button.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler)`. The code seems to work fine, and, like many others before me I'm sure, I'm left needing a bit of guidance about binding 'this'. Many thanks.

Comment: If it works it means you don't need to bind

Comment: If it’s an arrow function, `this` will automatically point to the instance, so binding is not necessary. If `clickHandler` was a method, then you’d need to bind `this`. See [How does the “this” keyword work?](/q/3127429/4642212).

Comment: It also depends if you use `this` inside of the handler

Answer (score -2):

Create test code to see all options:

```html
<my-component></my-component>

<script>
customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){
    function element ({ tag, ...props} ) {
       return Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
    }
    super().attachShadow({mode:"open"})
           .append(this.button = element({
                                 tag       : "button",
                                 innerText : "click me!",
                                 onclick   : (evt) => this.clicked(evt,1) // 1
                   }));
    this.button.addEventListener("click", (evt) => this.clicked(evt,2) ); // 2
    this.button.addEventListener("click", this.clicked ); // 3
    this.button.addEventListener("click", this.clicked.bind(this) ); // 4
  }
  clicked( evt, nr="no parameters!" ){
    console.log(evt.type, nr , "scope:", this.nodeName);
  }
})
</script>
```

1. The `onclick` *Event Handler **Property*** creates better readable code, IMHO;
   but you can only assign **one** per element
2. Can create multiple `click` handlers on **one** element, **and** pass arguments.
3. is for when you **never** want to access *scope* and parameters inside the class method
   IMHO, Do not use it! Because junior team members don't understand why behaviour is different from normal class methods.
4. (again IMHO) is oldskool notation,
   when you see it in code

   - it indicates something special is going on
   - or the developer is old and never learned or appreciated new *fat-arrow* syntax with *lexical* scope
   - or the developer is inexperienced, and copy-pasted code
   - or ...

   Note: you *can* pass arguments with `bind`. But it  will **prepend** them to the bound method;
   That means in `clicked(evt)` the `evt` parameter now becomes your ***first*** argument... more confusion for juniors.

Very deep dive on 'this': [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/4642212)